# Magento 2: Get total no. of colors available of Configurable Product

Tags: configurable-product, magento-2.1.7

I have configurable product which is combination of color and size. I have to get total no. of colors for the configurable product on the listing page.

I am able to get all the child products but not getting exact total of available colors.

There are 15 colors and 3 sizes so total child products is 45. I have to get total no. of colors.

Please give me some solution.

Comment: Just need to confirm.  you want total no of colors for particular configurable product or for all available configurable product on listing page.

Comment: Only for particular configurable product.

Answer (score 3):

You can use help of class `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable` refer [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/ffea3cd/app/code/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php)

Try like this

```
private $productRepository; 
...
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    ...
}

public function execute()
{
    $product = $this->productRepository->getById(83); //Configurable Product Id

    $colorAttributeId = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('color')->getId(); // Get Color Attribute Id
    $configurableAttrs = $product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product); // Get Used Attributes with its values

    if(isset($configurableAttrs[$colorAttributeId])){
        echo count($configurableAttrs[$colorAttributeId]['values']); // Gives you the count
        echo "<pre>";print_r($configurableAttrs[$colorAttributeId]['values']); // Give you values used
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. :-)
If i want to get hex colors code then what i need to do ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override "Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" class to show total no of color for a particular configurable product on listing page as below.

Create a simple module with registaration.php and etc/module.xml.

step 1. create di.xml under app/[company]/[module]/etc/di.xml and write below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="company\module\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
</config>
```

step 2. create ListProduct.php  under app/[company]/[module]/Block/Product/ and write below code.

```
<?php

namespace [company]\[module]\Block\Product;

class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct {

public function getProductDetailsHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product) {
       $html = '';
       $renderer = $this->getDetailsRenderer($product->getTypeId());
        if ($renderer) {
            if ($product->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
                $options = array();
                $productColor = array();
                foreach ($data as $attr) {
                    foreach ($attr as $p) {

                        if ($p['attribute_code'] == 'color') {
                            if (!in_array($p['option_title'], $productColor)) {
                                $productColor[] = $p['option_title'];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                 }
                $html = "Total No of colors is " . count($productColor);
             }
             $renderer->setProduct($product);
             return $html . $renderer->toHtml();
         }
         return '';
     }

}
```